# Streaming Web Audio API microphone data to disk on nodewebkit

Tags: node.js, stream, wav, node-webkit, web-audio-api

I'm working on a nodewebkit app that uses the Web Audio API to record microphone data and save it to disk.

I've used the RecordRTC framework, but it doesn't expose a way to stream the data to disk as the recording progresses (which is necessary given that the recordings could be longer than an hour).

I can't seem to find a good way to stream the data to disk using other methods either. If there is a proper way to do this, I would appreciate tips on what the proper tool for the job is.

However, the non-working solution I have now is:

1. Creating a ScriptProcessorNode with WebAudio API to access the PCM data
2. Create a readable stream buffer (using the stream-buffer module) and pipe it to a fileWriter (made with the wav module)
3. Translating that data to 16 bit ints in the onaudioprocess event and add them to the readable stream so they can be written

This hasn't worked because the ReadableStreamBuffer is only piping 20 bytes at a time to the fileWriter and not queueing all of the bytes coming from the microphone for some reason.

```
var wav = require('wav');
var streamBuffers = require("stream-buffers");

function convertFloat32ToInt16(buffer) {
  var l = buffer.length;
  var buf = new Int16Array(l);
  while (l--) {
    buf[l] = Math.min(1, buffer[l])*0x7FFF;
  }
  return buf.buffer;
}

var filePath = utils.getCwd() + '/recordings/demo.wav';
var fileWriter = new wav.FileWriter( filePath, {
  channels: 1,
  sampleRate: 48000,
  bitDepth: 16
});

var myReadableStreamBuffer = new streamBuffers.ReadableStreamBuffer({
    frequency:  0,        // in milliseconds.
    chunkSize: 2048        // in bytes.
});

myReadableStreamBuffer.pipe(fileWriter);

source.connect(scriptNode);
scriptNode.connect(context.destination);

scriptNode.onaudioprocess = function(e) {
    var arrayBuffer = convertFloat32ToInt16(e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0));
    myReadableStreamBuffer.put(arrayBuffer);
    // close  myReadableStreamBuffer and  run fileWriter.end() when recording is done
};
```

Comment: Could the frequency and chunkSize of the ReadableStreamBuffer have something to do with that? Just a wild guess.